# some manual calculations

Tags: probability

I have a ratio between two probabilities 
$$ \frac{(1-p)^{1000}+1000*p*(1-p)^{999}}{ \binom{1000}{2}*p^2*(1-p)^{998}}$$
and it is asked to show that this ratio is >1 (without a calculator)

$p=2/1000$

I arrived to this passage.
$$ \frac{(1-p)^{1000}+1000*p*(1-p)^{999}}{ \binom{1000}{2}*p^2*(1-p)^{998}}=
\frac{(1-p)^{2}+1000*p*(1-p)}{ 500*999*p}$$
Then the suggested solution says
$$ \frac{(1-p)^{2}+2*p*(1-p)}{ 999*p}$$
but i don't understant where does it come from?
it there something that I'm ignoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write ${1000 \choose 2}=\frac 12 \cdot 1000 \cdot 999$.  Divide numerator and denominator by $(1-p)^{998}$ and use the extra factor of $p$ in the denominator to cancel the $\frac {1000}2$